# JPA Annotations - how to merge two fields into one column for a join table?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

So I have two classes, a Route, and a BusStop. A Route 'Uses' two BusStop objects, one as a start, one as a destination. I need to have this relationship mapped via a join table, 'Uses'.

This join table doesn't need to distinguish if a BusStop is used for a start or destination. Basically I just need start and destination to become one column (with duplicates allowed) in this join table, so I can get a complete mapping of which routes use which stops.

Here is how I had it set up (assume getters and setters are there):

```
public class Route {
    @Id
    private String number;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int frequency;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(
        name = "Uses",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "number"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    )
    private BusStop start;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(
        name = "Uses",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "number"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    )
    private BusStop destination;
    ...
}

public class BusStop {
    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "Uses",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "number")
    )
    private Set<Route> routes;
    ...
}
```

Now the problem I'm having is that this results in a 'Uses' table that only ever has one of each Route id, though it successfully keeps duplicate stop ids. I'm assuming it has something to do with me trying to create two 'Uses' tables in the Route class?

So how exactly would be the correct way to go about this?

Comment: You can't, because you'd subsequently have no way of knowing which FK (start, or destination) it represents. Say you create a BusStop, and then add a Route to it (since BusStop OWNS the relation) ... how does the Route know whether it is start/destination? No info in the database to know that. If you want to retrieve a Route, you go to the join table, but have no way of knowing which is the start and which is the destination that it has.

Comment: How about if I had two sets of Route in the BusStop? Incoming and outgoing? Also I thought that Route should own the relation? Thanks anyway, I probably will end up just ditching the join table soon

Comment: 2 sets is the standard way of doing it, yes

Comment: So if I did have two sets of Route instead, would I be able to get this 'Uses' join table to work any better? If so, how? The problem I have currently is that only one stop from each Route is being entered into it

Comment: As ever "it all depends". A Route really ought to have multiple Stops, in order (i.e a List in the Route), rather than just a "start" and "destination" ... since the bus goes somewhere in between those ... but that part may be of no value in your system, only you know. Returning to your question, in Java terms a Set can typically have a particular object in it ONCE, whereas a List, or Multiset can have duplicates.

Comment: Yeah, it's an assignment and the specification itself is a bit convoluted and vague. We were just told that a Route needs a start and destination, that the Route to BusStop relationship is ManyToOne, and that a join table 'Uses' should link the two together, as simply a list of individual 'uses' of a stop by a route, regardless of whether its a start or destination.

Comment: I think I'm gonna give up and just not bother with the Uses table though, and just try a solution like ansh's below, as that seems to be the way most of my classmates went with it. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the much cleaner way to do this.

Here are my entities.

```
package com.ansh.entity;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "routes")
@Getter @Setter
public class Route {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "number")
    private String number;

    @Column(name = "frequency", nullable = false)
    private int frequency;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "start_id")
    private BusStop start;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "destination_id")
    private BusStop destination;
}
```

AND

```
package com.ansh.entity;

import com.google.common.collect.Sets;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "bus_stops")
@Getter @Setter
public class BusStop {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "start")
    private Set<Route> outgoingRoutes = Sets.newHashSet();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "destination")
    private Set<Route> incomingRoutes = Sets.newHashSet();

    public Set<Route> getRoutes() {
        return Sets.union(outgoingRoutes, incomingRoutes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of doing it this way and I may resort to it.. but the work is for an assignment and we were specifically asked to create a 'Uses' join table. Is there no way at all to get it working?

Comment: Can u please explain the BusStop to Route Relation. It is OneToMany is what way?
One-To-Many where BusStop is source OR destination OR both.

Comment: BusStop to Route is OneToMany as one BusStop is used by many Routes, at least that's how I was thinking of it. I guess it could be considered ManyToMany but that would mean merging start and destination in the Route class, which I can't do